# :not CSS Selector wild card to select a tags containing # in href

Tags: css, css-selectors, href

I am on a mission to select `a tag` containing `#` in it's href, I am trying from 1 day but unable to get the proper css class,

What I tried:
`a:not([href$="\\#\\"])`

Comment: Why would you think `:not` would be what you wanted?

Comment: I am just adding some css to all links to make it look better and show link preview but I don't want to select link with # as I used that css to display some link meta information with some js but I don't want to select link of my own domain so I just used ^ to check if it starts with my domain or not and * to check if the link is containing # or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard selector is used to select multiple elements simultaneously. It selects similar type of class name or attribute and use CSS property.

#### There are 3 wildcard css selectors

1. `*` Used to check if the selected thing contains the word or not. It is also known as containing wildcard.
2. `^` Wildcard to check if selected css attribute **starts** with the given word.
3. `$` Wildcard to check if selected css attribute **ends** with the given word.

In my case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
          
            /* Define styles */
            a:not([href*="#"]) {  /* WE USE * HERE to check if element contains */
                background: red;
                color: white;
            }
            h1 {
                color:white;
            }
            body {
                text-align:center;
                width:60%;
                background: black;
            }
            a {
               color: silver;
            }
            a[href^="#"] {
            color: blue;
            }
            a[href$="#"] {
            color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example containing # in url</h1>
          
        <!-- Since we have used * with #, all items with
             # in the above code are selected -->
        <a href="/">I am not having # in my url</a><br>
        <a href="/questions/68938789/not-css-selector-wild-card-to-select-a-tags-containing-in-href#">I am a link containing # at last.</a>
        <a href="#hello"> I am link containing # at start of href</a>
        <a href="hello#hello"> I am a link containing # in middle</a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">i am also not having # in my url like first link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more see

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/

Answer (score 2):

(Your title and your body content are conflicting. I'll go with the body content.)

It would be:

```
a[href*="#"]
```

From the spec:

```
E[foo*="bar"]: an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"

E[foo$="bar"]: an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors

Comment: Thank you so much, I also got a better answer and I posted it here, but it's not allowing me to select my own answer so I will select yours.

Comment: You're welcome. Refer to the link I posted for a description of the available selectors.

Comment: Yes I read the whole page it's an very good resource and it should be on top of google search. Thanks once again.